# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^4}(e^{u^{10}}-1)du}{x^{44}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^4}(e^{u^{10}}-1)du}{x^{44}}$$

We have a limit of "$\frac{0}{0}$" so we will us l'hopital:

$$[\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(x)]'=F'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)-F'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

So we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^{40}}\cdot 4x^3-1-(e^0-1)}{44x^{43}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^{40}}\cdot 4x^3-1}{44x^{43}}$$

How can I continue from here? or did I miss something?

Comment: Have a look at the function value for $x=0$. (IMO, this result is wrong.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust so the error must be here: $e^{x^{40}}\cdot 4x^3-1-(e^0-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By L'Hospital and by the chain rule,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^4}(e^{u^{10}}-1)du}{x^{44}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4x^3\left.(e^{u^{10}}-1)\right|_{u=0}^{x^4}}{44x^{43}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{x^{40}}-1}{11x^{40}}=\frac1{11}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let us begin by formally writing stuff down first - 
$[{\int_{0}^{f(x)}g(u) \cdot du}]' = g(f(x)) \cdot  f'(x)$

In our case, we have -

$f(x) = x^4$ and $g(u) = e^{u^{10}} - 1$

$f'(x) = 4x^3$, $g(f(x)) = e^{x^{40}} - 1$

So, the numerator term in the L'Hospital rule you have applied should be $4x^3 \cdot (e^{x^{40}} - 1)$ and not $4x^3 \cdot e^{x^{40}} - 1$.

Now, we need to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{4x^3 \cdot (e^{x^{40}} - 1)}{44 x^{43}}$
= $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{ (e^{x^{40}} - 1)}{11 x^{40}}$ = $\dfrac{1}{11}$

Comment: In more details it is $4x^3(e^{x^{40}}-1)-0(e^0-1)$?

Comment: I removed the hyphen after "be" and before $4x^3$ because it could be interpreted as a minus sign.  +1, great answer.